# Is there a way to test responsive CSS with Selenium?

Tags: css, ruby, testing, responsive-design, selenium-webdriver

The developers at my company have implemented our website to be CSS responsive, and I am confused how to leverage Selenium to test their work. I have been using Selenium WebDriver (Selenium 2) with Ruby all along for other aspects.

After doing some research online, I came across multiple tools but none worth automating with as they .. aaa... are just web tools to manually check with different screen sizes.

Some examples -

1. [Device Testing for Resonsive CSS Layouts (Manual)](http://tools.hyperspatial.com/web/devices/#form-top)
2. [Responsinator](http://www.responsinator.com/)
3. [Responsive.is](http://responsive.is)
4. [Responsivepx](http://responsivepx.com/) (much better as more control)

But I can achieve the above very easily using Selenium as well using sel2/ruby

```
@driver.manage.window.resize_to(480, 725) #iphone potrait
```

---

Need help with

- How to actually test if the css is "responsive" **automatically**?
- What are commonly used attributes/aspects to check if page is responding to window resizing?
- Has anyone used Selenium to QA responsive CSS?

Comment: The Web Tools mentioned above are really good for manual testing of Responsive Web Design

Comment: I have got another 2 tools and using for RWD testing: http://lab.maltewassermann.com/viewport-resizer/  and
http://responsive.victorcoulon.fr/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of two ways of doing this.

One - for each web element you can check its size, location, visibility, etc. After each resize you could compare those parameters with some previously specified values to check if layout has changed.

Second - image comparison. After each resize you could take a screenshot of the page and compare it to previously saved pattern. There are various image comparison libraries to achieve that. In our company we use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/). The image comparison however is not suitable for pages under development nor for the ones with changing content. You may get around this problem by hiding the parts of page that are prone to changes with javascript (this is doable with WebDriver).

I must admit I never had opportunity to test responsive pages neither manually nor automatically, so the above are just my ideas. I do use image comparison for testing "normal" pages, I am not sure if it will be suitable for responsive pages too.

**EDIT**

Unfortunately I don't know Ruby. Below is an example in Java I hope you can understand it and translate to Ruby somehow. The code simply prints the size and location of every element from the list.

```
org.openqa.selenium.Point point;
org.openqa.selenium.Dimension dimension;
        
List<WebElement> elementsList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//some/xpath"));
        
for (WebElement element : elementsList)
{
    point = element.getLocation();
    dimension = element.getSize();
    System.out.println("Element name: " + element.getTagName());
    System.out.println("Element size: " + dimension.height + "x" + dimension.width);
    System.out.println("Element location: " + point.x + ":" + point.y);
}
```

Note that every invocation of getLocation() and getSize() causes js to be executed (in order to obtain the values) and it costs time. That's why you should make just one call per element, don't use something like element.getSize().height + "x" + element.getSize().width - it would take twice as much time comparing to the example above.

In Ruby the above-mentioned methods are called element.location and element.size

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you have some sample code for size and location aspects?

Comment: Hey @JacekM, let me try to implement it in Ruby and get back to you.

Comment: Image comparison is expensive I think. @JacekM: Your code mentioned above retrieved size, location of elements,it's OK. How can I compare them with expected size and locatin?

Comment: @Ripon Al Wasim - I can think of many ways of doing it. I would probably store the reference values in database for future comparisons.
Another way would be checking how elements are positioned against each other instead of verifying their exact position and size. I guess the elements' relations would have to be hard-coded in such case

Comment: If we are already digging out this old thread I will add that I found out that using your own image comparison procedure which simply reads images into arrays and performs bit-by-bit comparison in a loop is actually faster than using ImageMagick...

Answer (score 11):

There is now a solution for automated testing of responsive design - Galen Framework.
I have been working on a tool that would allow to test the responsive design of web page as well as just layout of website for cross-browser compatibility. The tool is available here http://galenframework.com

It uses Selenium in order to open a web page in a browser, re-size the browser window to a needed size and then to get the location of elements on page. 
It has a special syntax for describing the page look on different devices (browser sizes)

Here is a small example of testing basic web page skeleton:

```
# Objects definition
=====================================
header                  id  header
menu                    css #menu
content                 id  content
side-panel              id  side-panel
footer                  id  footer
=====================================


@ all
-------------------------------
header
    inside: screen 0px top left right

menu
    centered horizontally inside: screen
    below: header 0px

content
    below: menu 0px
    inside:screen 0px left

@ desktop
--------------------------------
side-panel
    below: menu 0px
    inside: screen 0px right
    width: 300px
    near: content 0px right
    aligned horizontally top: content

@ mobile
--------------------------------
content, side-panel
    width: 100% of screen/width


side-panel
    below: content 0px
```

Later you can run tests either in a single command or you can also create a separate test suite where you have more actions to perform (e.g. inject custom javascript, or do something with WebDriver etc.). To run the above example with single command you do it like this:

```
galen check homepage.spec --url "http://example.com" --size "400x600" --include "mobile,all" --htmlreport "reports"
```

That was only the basics. There are more examples on official website.

Also there is an introduction article which explains how to use TDD approach (Test Driven Development) when designing a web page http://mindengine.net/post/2013-11-16-tdd-for-responsive-design-or-how-to-automate-testing-of-website-layout-for-different-devices/

Comment: Great tool ! Is it possible to use other browser, than Firefox ? IE ? Chrome ? Android ?

Comment: Sure. Later I will post an article on how to run Galen tests against Selenium Grid so you can make sure changes on your website do not break the layout on other browsers.

Comment: Also will be great to show how to make tests on different OS (Selenium-RC).

Comment: That would be tricky at the moment as the only operating system Galen supports are the desktop OS like: Windows, Mac, Linux. Actually Galen delegates this to Selenium Grid so anything that is in Grid is also accessible by Galen.
At the moment it cannot run on a real mobile devices as Selenium doesn't work well with getting location and dimension of elements on iOS and Android browsers. There is a way to fix that by using javascript functions inside browser to calculate object offset on page and size. But that is a different story and I am not sure when I will be able to try this out.

Comment: Galen also supports now image comparison

Answer (score 1):

If your main aim is to test changes in UI and selenium is not an absolute requirement you could use BBC Wraith - https://github.com/BBC-News/wraith very easy to setup and use.

Answer (score 0):

We can acheive this in multiple ways

**1. Screenshot comparison** : Using selenium webdriver go to the given website url and change the browser to different sizes and compare the screenshots.If both screenshots are same then the given website is not responsive.If both screenshots are different then given website is responsive. This method is not good because Lets assume if slideshows are present in given website while taking the screenshots of that website, the slideshow images present in the given website may change and we will get different screenshots so if we compare the screenshots we will get result as both screenshots are different and we may get response as the given site is responsive

**2. The document width :** Using selenium webdriver go to the given website url and change the browser to mobile device size and execute the javascript to get document width. If width is less than mobile devices maximum width we can assume that the given website is responsive

**3. Screenshot width :** Using selenium webdriver go to the given website url and change the browser to mobile device size and take the screenshot and get the width of the screenshot image. If width is less than mobile devices maximum width we can assume that the given website is responsive. I tested multiple sites with this approach and got the expected result Steps to check given site is responsive or not.
 
See more about coding at: http://jagadeeshmanne.blogspot.in/2014/03/checking-website-is-responsive-or-not.html